# easy way to implement vr alongside list elements w/out tables?

Tags: html, css

I edit and format a lot of lengthy text documents using HTML. Quite often I have to edit lists with elements that contain 5 or 10 or more paragraphs, which is a long stretch before the readers sees the next list element to remind them they are reading listed info (I hope that makes sense).

Anyway, I wonder if there is an easier way than using tables to generate a vr (vertical rule) that begins on the next line after an `<li>` tag and runs alongside multiple paragraphs until the closing `</li>` tag is reached, signalling to the reader that they are still reading information/details belonging to a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add something like:

```
.vrc{border-left:3px coral solid;}
.vrt{border-left:6px white solid;}
```

in between your `<style>` tags, and then you could implement your list elements like:

```
<li class="vrc"><div class="vrt">
```

the `.vrt` css def. adds a little buffer between the text and the colored vertical bar that runs vertically alongside it. Alter the px amount to suit your prefs. or simply don't remove it altogether.

Just be sure your closing `</li>` tag comes after the closing `</p>` tag of the last paragraph in the list element.